# How to get AIC from Conway–Maxwell-Poisson regression via COM-poisson package in R?

Tags: r

Is there an easy way to get AIC for a Conway–Maxwell-Poisson regression from COM-poisson package in R?

see http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/COMPoissonReg/COMPoissonReg.pdf

I am not able to find build in `loglik` function nor `AIC`

Shall I use `AIC(glm of poisson fit) - chisq(cmp_fit) + 2`?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out myself.

`cmp` calls `ComputeBetasAndNuHat` which returns a list which has `objective` as minusloglik

So I can change the function `cmp` to get this value.